# Help understanding RV/Marine battery chargers

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

I am trying to understand how modern 3-stage marine/RV lead-acid battery charge systems work. It's very common to wire a charger in parallel with both the battery bank and the "house" power.  This means that when plugged in, the charger is both charging up the batteries *and* powering any DC electronics.

My understanding of [IUoU Charging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUoU_battery_charging) is that during the "Uo" phase the charger puts out constant voltage until the current draw drops below a given threshold. If the house electronics are drawing from the charger, then how could the charger possibly know what that threshold is? Shouldn't it be quite common for the charger to *never* hit that threshold and constantly overcharge the batteries (e.g. if the house refrigerator is in the circuit)?

Comment: That's a very good question. I think there is a timer that keeps on applying that over-voltage up to a set amount of time and then it drops to the float charge level. Unless the charger has a way of comparing the currents in and out of the battery, I wonder how else would it "know". Also, if the draw is larger than the charger's maximum current, there's another question of what does a charger do in that situation? Probably switches back to the constant-current stage.

Comment: @EdinFifić -  Right, I was also thinking the charger could turn itself off periodically to measure what voltage the system drifts down to and use that measurement for .... something... It seems like a fairly touchy algorithm though, and it's just strange that I haven't found any mention of the problem in the manuals I've been reading through.

Comment: Apparently, they assume that batteries will be charged out of a circuit or with an insignificant load.

Comment: @EdinFifić do you happen to have a source for that? I couldn't find any mention of limits for parallel loads in any of the manuals I read. Some chargers do have an auxiliary DC output, but even their diagrams show the main inverter just hooked up in parallel with the charger and batteries (e.g. https://imgur.com/a/h6pGcBh)

Comment: I don't think they would need to mention such limits because you know a charger can't supply more than its maximum current or the current used during the constant-current stage.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not talking about hitting the maximum current limits of the charger.  What I mean is that if there is too much parallel load, then the charger will presumably stay in the "absorption" phase forever thinking that it's charging an infinitely large battery.  If that's the case, then I would think that charger manuals would warn about this and mention that you shouldn't leave your monster stereo cranked and your blenders running for 24 hours while you charge your battery.

Comment: Lead-acid car batteries start producing hydrogen above 13.4V (which means dissolving/losing  the electrolyte). Keeping their voltage at 14.4V for extended periods of time is bound to significantly shorten their life. That's why any serious "smart" charger should include a timer to make ensure no excessive overcharge.

Comment: I finally did find a manual that mentions charging under load: https://www.samlex.com/wp-content/uploads/Manual-SEC-1245_1260_1280_2425_2440E.pdf

Answer (score 0):

When there’s a load, the charger current will be split between the load and the battery. The charger can still monitor voltage at that time.

When the load is removed the charger can revert to the charging profile, terminating to float voltage at the end.

Reapply load and the process starts all over, depending on how much the battery gets discharged. So a refrigerator cycling on and off would make the charger keep switching modes, based on sensed voltage and its calculation of battery state-of-charge.

The charger can (well, could) also monitor current in and out of the battery to help figure out battery state of charge - that is, ‘count coulombs’ as some Li-ion chargers do. But for lead-acid, mainly the voltage method is used. More here: https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_measure_state_of_charge

Comment: Good point, most refrigerators wouldn't act as a constant load as long as their insulation is reasonable - the compressor would turn on only occasionally to keep things cool. If the load never cycles off (e.g. floodlights are left on) then the charger would have no way to determine the difference between the load draw and the battery charging right? In that case, would even modern chargers just stay in the Uo absorption phase?

Comment: Also, in the case of a refrigerator load, it's not like the charger is properly accounting for the load. It's just "not a big deal" because that load will hopefully be on for less time than it takes to overcharge and damage the batteries?